# Converting query developed using conditions in PHP to a stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I have this query which is concatenated based on conditions in PHP. I am having hard time to convert it in a stored procedure.

```
           $sql = "SELECT   cu.user_id,
                    cu.contact_id,
                    cu.email_address, 
                    cu.first_name, 
                    cu.last_name, 
                    cu.admin, 
                    cl.description as admin_label,
                    cu.admin_available, 
                    cu.date_available,
                    cu.auth_exp_level,
                    CONVERT(varchar, date_logged_on, 103) AS date_logged_on,
                    def_auth_email,
                    (select count(*) from web_auth where account_code = '$acctcode' 
                    and auth_user_id = cu.user_id) as cnt_users
            FROM    web_users_vw cu
                    left outer join bcs_lists cl on cl.group_id = 'usertype' and cl.item = cu.admin
            WHERE cu.account_code = '$acctcode' ";
    /* Conditional sql starts here*/
if(!empty($user_type)) {
        $user_type_ary = preg_split('#(?<!\\\)\|#', $user_type);
        $user_type_str = "'";
        foreach ($user_type_ary as $user_type){
            if (!empty($user_type)){
                $user_type_str .= $user_type . "','";
            }
        }
        $user_type_str = rtrim($user_type_str, ",'");
        $user_type_str .= "'";
        $sql .= "AND admin in ($user_type_str) ";
    }
    if($admin != 'S' && $admin != 'V') {
        $sql .= "AND admin <> 'S' ";
    }
    if(!empty($cc_code)) {
        $sql .= "AND EXISTS ( SELECT user_id FROM web_cc WHERE user_id = cu.user_id AND account_code = 
'$acctcode' AND cc_code = '$cc_code') ";
    }
    if(!empty($loc_id)) {
        $sql .= "AND EXISTS ( SELECT user_id FROM web_locations WHERE user_id = cu.user_id AND account_code 
= '$acctcode' AND loc_id = '$loc_id') ";
    }
    if(!empty($approver)) {
        $sql .= "AND EXISTS ( SELECT user_id FROM web_auth WHERE user_id = cu.user_id AND account_code = 
 '$acctcode' AND auth_user_id = '$approver') ";
    }

    /* Conditional sql ends here*/

    $sql .= "ORDER BY email_address";
```

I have converterd it in

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procName
@acctcode varchar(15), 
@cc_code varchar(15) = '', 
@loc_id varchar(10) = '', 
@approver varchar(50) = '',
@user_type varchar(15) = '',
@admin varchar(1)  = ''
AS 
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @UserTypes TABLE (Item VARCHAR(7999))
    insert into @UserTypes select * from SplitStrings(@user_type,',')
  SELECT cu.user_id,
                        cu.contact_id,
                        cu.email_address, 
                        cu.first_name, 
                        cu.last_name, 
                        cu.admin, 
                        cl.description as admin_label,
                        cu.admin_available, 
                        cu.date_available,
                        cu.auth_exp_level,
                        CONVERT(varchar, date_logged_on, 103) AS date_logged_on,
                        def_auth_email,
                        (select count(*) from sweb_auth where account_code = @acctcode 
                        and auth_user_id = cu.user_id) as cnt_users
                FROM    web_users_vw cu
                        left outer join bcs_lists cl on cl.group_id = 'usertype' and cl.item = cu.admin
                WHERE cu.account_code = @acctcode

                
**///The conditional sql generated part based on php here///**
      
      ORDER BY cu.email_address
```

I cannot develop SQL where PHP is using certain conditions to add to SQL if the condition is true or not. I tried it using CASE, AND OR , <>, NOT NULL combinations but I can't. Can someone help, or guide me how to accomplish it.

Comment: In simple terms you just use a logical `OR` i.e. `WHERE (@MyParam is null or exists (select 1 from SomeTable where id = @MyParam))` and repeat that for all your conditions. I.e. either the parameter wasn't passed in *OR* the condition involving the parameter was met. That will sometimes cause performance issues though, in which case you might want to do down the dynamic SQL route.

Comment: THINK about your code. `@user_type` is 15 characters. You split that value and insert it into a column `Item` of 7999 characters. Do you see an inconsistency here? And why 7999? But Erland has a wealth of information this sort of thing [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and [using tvps](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). His entire site should be bookmarked.